# How to use RestSharp's AddFile() method to send httpContext.Request.Files[0]?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp to call .NET Web API.

I am sending the uploaded excel file to web api. Below code works perfectly fine on local machine.

But on the server, we don't have permission to save the uploaded file. 
**I am looking for alternate method for `restRequest.AddFile("content", location)` that accept `HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = httpContext.Request.Files[0].`**

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:56360");
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("api/excelupload/Upload");

int readWriteTimeout = restRequest.ReadWriteTimeout > 0
    ? restRequest.ReadWriteTimeout
    : ReadWriteTimeout;
    restRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = readWriteTimeout;
    restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
    restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
    restRequest.AddFile("content", location);
    restRequest.AddParameter("DetailLineNumber", "4");
    var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
```

File reading on API.

```
foreach (var content in provider.Contents)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName))
                    {
                        postedData.File = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    }
               }
```

Comment: It looks like there is a general problem https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/1272

Comment: @wp78de but that question is closed without any suggestion or answers.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used RestSharp for a while. Could you use a Stream? Something like this:

```
public RestRequest CreateUploadFileRequest(string path, string filename, Stream fileStream)
{
    var request = new RestRequest (Method.POST);
    request.Timeout = int.MaxValue; //test
    request.Resource = "/files/{path}";
    request.AddParameter ("path", path, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
    //Need to add the "file" parameter with the file name
    request.AddParameter ("file", filename);
    request.AddFile ("file", s => StreamUtils.CopyStream (fileStream, s), filename);

    return request;
}
```